# Virtual Machine with dedicated Mouse, keyboard, monitor

Tags: networking, virtualbox, keyboard, mouse, kvm-virtualization

I have installed Ubuntu desktop as a virtual machine, and made it so that the guest can be reached from other devices on the network.  I was wondering if there is a way to remote into the guest, and dedicate a mouse and keyboard to this guest?

Could this be accomplished with a KVM, or some alternative hardware/software?

Comment: That kind of device is usually called a "thin client".

Comment: You might look at TeamViewer application. www.teamviewer.com

Comment: @NickWeinberg Yes you might be correct as i need is a standalone device that can remote without installing any software

Comment: @heynnema I'm sorry i need is a standalone device like a kvm switch or etc...

Comment: A vnc server already exists in Ubuntu. You might look into it. You *did* ask for a hardware/software solution. **Synergy** might be another solution. Check at https://symless.com/synergy/?_ab5&utm_expid=35973112-19.xUn6IQjSRFmhb7QoIsQbgw.1

Comment: What is the host os for this ubuntu desktop machine. virt-manager if installed on a client can do this but you want with no software installed.

Comment: To make it clear... I need a device alternative to switch or kvm switch to access my qemu vai Ip and remote it to a monitor keyboard mouse etc without needing and other pc to remote it. I want to provide my staff to use only virtual machine remote to use their job like libreoffice note browser etc.

Hope Everybody understand my needed Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can connect one extra monitor, one extra keyboard and one extra mouse directly to your host. HDMI cable can be easily more than 20 meters long, active USB extensions are also available.

In VirtualBox manager go to **Settings -> USB -> Add new USB Filter** (it is a small image with a "+" sign) and add the keyboard and mouse, so that they do not interfere with the host. Probably you will have to install VirtualBox Extension Pack - make sure to install it yourself so as not to violate "Personal Use Agreement" :-)

When you start a virtual machine, make it run on the dedicated monitor in full-screen mode.

To put it in autostart, create a command from the list of virtual machines by right-click -> **Create Shortcut** on Desktop.

Negative side of this solution is that you can also work on that machine as it is an extension of your desktop.